# Display API JSON response in template - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I want to display data on my website from JSON file from URL.
I work on Angular and I've create a HttpClient in my component. Code below show all document in console, so here is my question.

```ts
  let resp = this.http.get("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1w2vpgbwImaQGCbpMqZ3P0NC93tuVved0oOFc9Zr22dU/1/public/full?alt=json");
   resp.subscribe((data)=>console.log(data));
```

Can I show a specify elements from this JSON file?

I want to display data from: feed -> entry -> gs$cell -> $t on my website.
How I should start, what I need?

I have add a picture how the JSON array looks and what elements I want to get and show on my website.

[image]

Comment: Try this on your console `fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1w2vpgbwImaQGCbpMqZ3P0NC93tuVved0oOFc9Zr22dU/1/public/full?alt=json").then(r => r.json()).then(d => console.log(d.feed.entry.map(e => e['gs$cell']['$t'])))`.

Comment: @bertdida thanks for your reply! I've try this on my console and yes, this show me data that I want, but I want display this data on my website, so I want transfer it to HTML and save in table for example. Any suggestions how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Store API response in a class variable i.e `data`, assume sample data

```
  data = {
    feed: {
      entry: [
        { gs$cell: { $t: 'Nazwa' } },
        { gs$cell: { $t: 'pazwa' } },
        { gs$cell: { $t: 'shuzwa' } }
      ]
   }
 }
```

Accessing directly in template

```
<div *ngFor="let d of this.data.feed.entry">{{d.gs$cell.$t}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem is how to extract the data.

I can't use your HttpClient so I will be using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API for demonstration.

```js
async function getData() {
  const endpoint =
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1w2vpgbwImaQGCbpMqZ3P0NC93tuVved0oOFc9Zr22dU/1/public/full?alt=json";

  // const json = await http.get(endpoint);

  const response = await fetch(endpoint);
  const json = await response.json();

  const { feed } = json;
  const { entry: feedEntries } = feed;

  return feedEntries.map((entry) => {
    const { gs$cell } = entry;
    const { $t } = gs$cell;
    return $t;
  });
}

(async () => {
  const data = await getData();
  console.log(data);

  // do whatever you wan't with the data, use it on your template maybe?
})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works good, but I want to display this data in table, where the "Nazwy" and "Numery" are names of the columns. In console "data" is an array with 11 elements, and the two first elements data[0] and data[1] are the names of columns. Now it would be quite difficult to show data on website in table(in fact I want to display data exactly how it looks on google sheets)